# How can I name a value to some for easy referral later on?

Tags: c++

I was wondering how I can name a value something so I can refer to it later on in the code as that name instead of the value itself. If anyone is familiar with HTML you can name a tag with the "name, class, and div" tags for referral later on. That is what I would like to do in c++.

More specifically I coded a script that will obtain the value of a registry and that value is a IP address and I would like to name that IP address so I can easily refer to it when coding automatic ping script.

Anything will be very much a predicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an object:

```
Type IP = value;
```

or alternatively a `const` object, if the IP value shouldn't be changed during the program:

```
const Type IP = value;
```

(where `Type` is the type of the IP value and `value` is the value).

As an example, if you want to use a [string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to memorize the `IP` address:

```
const std::string IP = "127.0.0.1";
```

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0083cd3fd8235b28)